# Why the HttpContext is null within event receivers, console applications and timer jobs

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers, timer-jobs, console-application, httpcontext

Why the **HttpContext is null** within **event receivers, console applications and timer jobs.**

```
HttpContext httpctx = HttpContext.Current;
```

I googled about it and found that its by design. But  why by design? There should be specific reason or purpose behind it. As a newbie i just want to be more clear about sharepoint concepts. Thank you.

Comment: Because they do not run in a web process (they run outside of the IIS)

Comment: Thanks robert for quick reply. Your answer make the sense but can you please give more information.

Answer (score 4):

Think about what HTTP is and what an HTTP context would represent.

HTTP is the protocol that web servers use. Event receivers, timer jobs and console apps aren't served from a web server over HTTP. There's no request and no response, hence no HTTP context.

Comment: Thanks Derek for answer. Ok I understood the Console app is not running on web server, but then where actually the event receivers and timer jobs runs?  because these are deployed on sharepoint site !

Comment: They run in (non-web) separate process on the server. Timer jobs run on Owstimer.exe and event receivers run in a different process as well (can't remember which right now). Think of it this way: if it doesn't happen in a browser, it's (probably) not an HTTP context.